# C# excel interop: DateTime values not written out consistently

Tags: c#, string, excel, datetime

I'm trying to use interop to create an excel spreadsheet. One of the columns is a date/time column, and the format I'm imposing on the data isn't being reflected in the spreadsheet.

```
if (dt.Rows[i][col] is DateTime)
{
    var tmp = (DateTime)dt.Rows[i][col];
    val = tmp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
cell.Value = val; // cell is a range object...set the cell's Value property
```

Some of the data in the spreadsheet are of the form `30/05/2004 21:59:23` (correct) but others are of the form `1/6/2004  4:18:35 AM` (why isn't the month/date correct...why the AM/PM?). I've tried creating new `DateTime` objects each time (extracting only the relevant properties for the spreadsheet) but this has been unsuccessful.

Why would the string format not be respected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With assigning to property `Value` you are providing exactly just the value but not the formatting. In some cases Excel might agree on the actual format you provided, in other cases not.

If formatting is important, I suggest writing the `Value` just as a `DateTime` and using the `NumberFormat` property of the cell to define the formatting.

If you provide an explicit format, I would stick to system formats instead of custom formats where possible. Usually this avoids annoyances for the users.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is Excel is converting the string to a date value using it's default formatting (mm/dd/yyyy).  Since `30/05/2004 21:59:23` is not a valid date in that format it leaves it as a string.

I would recommend using numeric values for the dates instead of string and let Excel format them (or update the date format programmatically):

```
var tmp = (DateTime)dt.Rows[i][col];
val = tmp.ToOADate();
```